# Disable all comboboxes of form on one click in extjs

Tags: extjs

I am working in extjs. I have to disable fields of my form.

I have used below function.

```
        var form = Ext.getCmp('frmTender').getForm();

        fields = form.getFields();

        Ext.each(fields.items, function (f) {

            f.inputEl.dom.disabled = true;

        }
```

Its working for textfields but not for comboboxes and checkboxes. So Please help me how

can I  disable all comboboxes

of my form.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the setDisabled method of the Ext component.

```
 f.setDisabled(true);
```

in place of

```
 f.inputEl.dom.disabled = true;
```

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-method-setDisabled

Comment: thanks John...........working, But By this my window get grey in colour. But i don't want that, My window should remain white, Only fields must get grey

Comment: Now, I have used
 f.setReadOnly(true);

in place of

 f.inputEl.dom.disabled = true; Its working

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't like the disabling of fields in extjs. The labels are getting greyed out too. I'm using it this way.

```
//JS
var form = Ext.getCmp('frmTender').getForm();
fields = form.getFields();
Ext.each(fields.items, function (f) {
  f.inputEl.dom.readonly = true; //f.setReadOnly(true)
  f.inputEl.addCls('x-custom-field');
};

//CSS
.x-custom-field
{
  background: none; //#ccc
}
```